# Elixir convert struct to map

Tags: dictionary, struct, elixir, telegram-bot

I'm trying to convert a struct to a map to be able to clean all the nil values

I'm currently using this code

```
  case Nadia.get_updates  do
    {:ok, results} ->
      Map.from_struct(results)
      |> Enum.filter(fn {_, v} -> v != nil end)
      |> Enum.into(%{})
```

Note: Nadia.get_updates returns the following structure:
https://hexdocs.pm/nadia/Nadia.Model.Update.html#t:t/0

Yet I'm always receiving the following error: no function clause matching in Map.from_struct/1

Comment: Maybe `results` is a list of these structs? Not only one struct?

Answer (score 121):

Since [v0.15](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/commit/380bf1e279e782d600a266cc6a3782ece0a2bf95) we have `Map.from_struct/1` which does exactly this.

```
defmodule User do
  defstruct [:name]
end

Map.from_struct(%User{name: "valim"})
#=> %{name: "valim"}
```

Comment: Haha! Judging by the upvote I've been here before... perhaps I should get a tattoo :)

Answer (score 17):

There's another trick

```
my_struct = %MyStruct{}
my_map = Map.delete my_struct, :__struct__
```

Comment: `mymap = Map.delete(mystruct, :__meta__) |> Map.delete(:__struct__)`

Comment: @nelsonic - I actually like the approach that Juliano suggested

    Map.from_struct(%User{name: "valim"})

is better way to do that

Comment: Yeah, `Map.from_struct/1` is definitely good for regular structs. But when the struct is an Ecto changeset `Map.from_struct/1` won't fully work so we need: `mymap = Map.from_struct(changeset) |> Map.delete(:__meta__)`

Answer (score 2):

```
get_updates([{atom, any}]) ::
  {:ok, [Nadia.Model.Update.t]} |
  {:error, Nadia.Model.Error.t}
```

If successful it returns a list of Nadia.Model.Update.t. That's why you get that error.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I wrote a library that will do this kind of thing for you automagically w/o having to pull the data structure apart.

https://github.com/philosophers-stone/transform

This is from the test code:

```
test "implement scrub of empty values from map" do
  data = %{ :a => nil, :b => "", :c => "a"}
  replace_empty = fn(string, _d) -> if( string == "", do: nil , else: string) end
  replace_nil = fn(map, _depth) ->  for {k, v} <- map, v != nil , into: %{}, do: {k, v} end
  potion = %{ BitString => replace_empty, Map => replace_nil}

  assert PhStTransform.transform(data, potion) == %{:c => "a"}

end
```

Note, if data was a list of maps this would still work just fine. The PhStTransform library will just keep pulling the data apart until it finds a map. In your case you would use a replace_nil function that worked on the kinds of structs you are interested in.